# How do I create an image element and its attributes in one go?

Tags: javascript, object

EDIT: Changed the question and title to reflect my intent throughout as per Felix's suggestion

What I want to do is create a subobject "obj" that works as follows:

```
upperMostObject.obj      //This is an image
upperMostObject.obj.src  //This is an attribute of the image
```

and the way I want to be able to create it, that is, what I am trying to achieve is

```
var imgCollection = {
    catImage: document.createElement("img"),
    catImage: {
        src: "http://whatever.source.com/image.png",
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
    },
}
```

But the former, in this case `catImage: document.createElement("img")` gets overwritten.

Comment: So, you want to have a string (`"topValue"`) with properties (`subObj`)?

Comment: you can define [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) function for `obj`

Comment: Ah @FelixKling. Looking at it that way I think I understand why it won't work.

What I was trying to do however was make an image element inside an object and set the image properties in the same go. I'll update my post to clarify.

Comment: You probably want to edit the question to provide a better example throughout and change the title again.

Comment: @FelixKling I edited it. I hope this is more correct this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am trying to achieve is ...

This seems like a job for [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
var imgCollection = {
    catImage: Object.assign(document.createElement("img"), {
        src: "http://whatever.source.com/image.png",
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
    })
};
```

`Object.assign` copies the properties of the other arguments to the first argument and returns the first argument. Follow the link for a polyfill.

Answer (score 9):

You need to either use a `String` *object* (not primitive), or define a custom `toString()` method for your object.

The first method:

```
var upperMostObject = {};
upperMostObject.obj = new String("topValue"); // as a String object
upperMostObject.obj.subObj = "subValue";
```

This works because a string primitive cannot hold properties, while a `String` object can.

Beware when using `String` objects that while you can compare using loose equals (`==`), you can't with strict equals (`===`). Also `typeof someStringObject` will be `"object"`, not `"string"`.

The second method (can be done "in one go"):

```
var upperMostObject = {
    obj: {
        toString: function(){return "topValue"},
        subObj: "subValue"
    },
}
```

This works because any time you cast the object to a string (eg `upperMostObject.obj == 'topValue'`), it will internally call its `toString` method.

Comment: You could also add `subObj` to `String.prototype`, although that's a pretty evil option.

Comment: It would be worth pointing out the disadvantages of using a string object.

Comment: @Scimonster Thank you very much for the response. I learned something new even though I'm trying to find a way to have the upperMostObject.obj be an image element. I learned something new however. And I apologize for not including my intent in the original question and I have updated it for what I'm trying to achieve. I apologize dearly for not explaining in more detail because this is such a good answer.